# Realizar determinada tarefa em uma data e hora específica

Tags: java, thread, data, calendar, task

Estou tentando desenvolver um pequeno sistema que envia um *e-mail* toda terça-feira as 08:00 da manhã.

Porém estou um pouco confuso, já consigo enviar o e-mail e verificar se é terça-feira, mas não sei se está correto.

O sistema continua rodando, porém como ainda não estou verificando se é 08:00 da manhã ele não deveria enviar vários emails sem parar, já que a única condição para envio de emails é ser Terça?

Aqui está o código:

```
public void gerarAviso() {
    Timer timer = null;
    if (timer == null) {
        timer = new Timer();
        Calendar data = Calendar.getInstance();
        TimerTask tarefa = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.err.println("DATA: " + data);
                if (data.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.TUESDAY){
                    System.out.println("É terça feira");
                    EnviaEmail e = new EnviaEmail();
                    e.enviaEmail("email@email.com");
                }else {
                        System.out.println("Não é terça feira!");
                }    
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(tarefa, data.getTime());
    }
}
```

Comment: Enviar vários e-mails? Esse bloco de código está sendo chamado dentro de algum laço de repetição como `for` ou `while`?

Comment: Enviar só um mesmo. Só quero envia-lo toda terça feira as 8:00 da manhã, ou seja, o sistema ficará rodando sem parar

Comment: Estou me referindo a sua pergunta `ele não deveria enviar vários emails sem parar, já que a única condição para envio de emails é ser Terça?`... Com certeza ele não deveria enviar **vários** *e-mails*, o bloco de código só será executado uma vez. (A não ser que ele esteja sendo chamado dentro de um laço de repetição)

Comment: Aa sim, isso seria pela condição, ele deve enviar apenas um porém ele continua a ser executado na Task.

Comment: Mas tem algo dando errado com esse código? Qual é o problema que você precisa solucionar?

Comment: O problema é que eu não sei se está correto, ele faz a primeira verificação e verifica se é terça feira porém não sei uma maneira de testar pra ver se ele continua executando. A única maneira que enxergo seria deixar ele rodando até amanhã

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método **schedule(TimerTask task, Date time)** só executa a tarefa uma vez.
Vou recomendar você a usar o método: **scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, Date firstTime, long period)** para que o método seja repetido dia a dia.
Lembrando que o period é medido em milisegundos.

Também pode ser feito um loop manualmente que espera um dia para verificar o dia da semana e enviar o e-mail.

Fonte: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: Obrigado @Shura16. faço uma verificação a cada 1 hora pra ver se o dia é terça e se são 08:00. Dessa forma o sistema fica sempre rodando e fazendo a verificação.

Comment: Também pode ser, tomaria cuidado para verificar apenas a hora e não os minutos e segundos. Se por algum motivo houver alguma demora no sistema e passar desses segundos ou minutos a tarefa não será executada.